# Bottom Navigation View Disabled states

Tags: java, android

**Дано:** `Bottom Navigation View` при выборе элемента background выбранного элемента меняется

**Нужно:** изменить background для определенного элемента.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так чтоб при выборе определенного элемента его background не изменился, а другие элементы работали в нормальном режиме, если выбрал элемент, то background сменился

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar/36033640 Там создаётся селектор и в xml прописывается disabled state

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да я читал это, но не совсем понял куда они добавили этот `selector` и [тут](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0) читал но не понял чего, не моглибы помочь?

Comment: Я не знаю с какого места вам помогать. Также не очень понятно что именно вам нужно. Попробуйте в `xml` добавить `android:enabled="true"` для нужного элемента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитав много ответов на stackoverflow решение проблемы нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33586004/5564588)

```
MenuItem item = drawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_something);
item.setCheckable(true);
item.setChecked(true);
```